# what exactly do UX Designer mean in the web design field?

Tags: website-design, web-app, experience, ux-designer

What I mean by this question is how can a person be an UX designer just by making a **STATIC** high fidelity mockup on a piece of software like "Photoshop" or "Sketch" or whatever.

Does not the words "User experience" mean by itself "movement", "motion" , "flow" and so on?

Does not being an UX Designer requires to actually make something real, palpable, usable in order to create an experience? I'm talking about knowing how to create what you've made in "Photoshop".

Am I totally wrong about this?

Comment: Who says making a mockup is in itself a piece of UX design work?

Comment: I saw on "dribble", "behance" people who are calling themselves "UX designer" and they do not know how to HTML/CSS/JS. That's why I'm asking

Comment: Well, designing isn't the same as developing. HTML/CSS/JS is part of front end dev qualities, IxD/VD/IA/Usability testing/Target group identification/+loads are part of UX qualities.

Comment: How can you conduct usability testing through a static image ?

Comment: The mockup presented on Dribble may just a fragment of all user centered design work that has gone into the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is more like the user interface. The mockups and the motion the flow etc... are the result of how you are going to communicate the desired user experience.

User Experience is what emotions, what state of mind or usability you want to achieve for the user that will interact with your website/app or whatever you design.
So the person who is UX designer should get (probably from marketing research) of what do your target audience except to receive(or what you want them to receive) upon using your product 
A simplistic example would be like this:

A client (lets say a bank) wants to improve the brand image and give the feeling to the customers that is:

1. Modern,
2. up to date
3. and cares about its customers

Now the marketing department should research the target audience and give briefing to the user experience.
Then the user experience department will analyze and describe what should be done to cover the demands of the client to improve the brand image
a simplistic approach would be

1. modern ---> this means it must be something for the smart phones(an app or an accessory)
2. up to date ----> this means the design of it should follow latest trends
3. cares about customer ----> this means (for a bank customer) fast and secure transanctions, so whatever you create must scream I'm secure I'm fast.
   after this is done the user experience department briefs the design department and they produce the User Interface for the User Experience described.

Hope this helps you abit, and again i point out that this is simplistic explanation

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, UX is not all about making a mockup.
UI is what you see in the app/website and UX is what you feel when you are using it.UI play a role in the way you feel about the app.A mockup define the way UI looks. This is just a part of UX.

Comment: Ok, so this means that you have to build it in order to feel it? Otherwise how can you feel a static image?